# Add classes to specific element tags on entire document

Tags: javascript

I am looking to add classes to specific element tags on an entire document with vanilla Javascript.

So far this is what I have (which does not work):

```
var themeHeading1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');
themeHeading1.classList.add('text-3xl','font-extrabold','leading-normal','md:text-6xl','md:leading-normal','text-3xl');
```

I found another piece of code that works, but I find it to extensive to constantly update and would be looking for a solution more like the above mentioned code:

```
var themeHeading1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')
var length = themeHeading1.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  themeHeading1[i].className = themeHeading1[i].className + " text-3xl font-extrabold leading-normal md:text-6xl md:leading-normal text-3xl";
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: For why the first piece of code doesn't work, see [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10693845). As for the second, why do you think it's a problem?

Comment: themeHeading1 is an array, that is what your code doesn't works. You will need to iterate over the elements

Comment: @lissettdm it's an HTMLCollection, not an array.

Comment: @lissettdm `themeHeading1` is **not** an Array. It's an ["array-like"](https://www.nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/06/advanced-javascript-objects-arrays-and-array-like-objects/#:~:text=Array%2Dlike%20objects%20look%20like,elements%20and%20a%20length%20property.&text=They're%20all%20stored%20in,is%20automatically%20created%20%2F%2F%20arguments.) node list.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the idea is you will need to iterate over the elements, I am sorry if I was not to specific about the type

Comment: And of course I agree with you about using querySelectorAll() over  document.getElementsByTagName()

Comment: @VLAZ already explained to you why your code does not work; anyway it should also be noted that it is a good practice to have only one `<h1>` tag per page/document. If you comply to that best practice, you can avoid looping through the HTML Collection returned by `document.getElementsByTagName()` and directly select the only `<h1>` with `var themeHeading1 = document.querySelector('h1')`; then your code should work.

Comment: @secan *"it is a good practice to have only one <h1> tag per page/document*" <-- That's a common misconception and a subject of a never ending debate. There is no established "best practice" around this. What's important is to have properly sectioned documents. Multiple `<h1>` elements (that create a proper document outline) are perfectly fine just as multiple Heading 1 paragraphs in a Word document contribute to a proper document structure there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use querySelectorAll with a selector so that it returns an array.

```
document
.querySelectorAll("h1")
.forEach((heading) =>
  heading.classList.add(
    "text-3xl",
    "font-extrabold",
    "leading-normal",
    "md:text-6xl",
    "md:leading-normal",
    "text-3xl"
  )
);
```

Comment: How does this explain why the OP's first attempt didn't work? Why is what you've shown better?

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a "live" collection of matching elements. Because it's a colleciton, it doesn't have individual DOM object properties like all DOM elements do, like `classList`. If you want to affect each element within the collection, you'll have to loop over the collection as in your second example.

By the way, don't use [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) to get you the collection as this is a legacy method that returns a "live" node list, which can cause performance issues. Instead, use [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) where you'll pass a valid CSS selector.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining, I am new to JS but the information provided makes sense now.